# Why two object are not equals after i save with serializable

Tags: java, equals, serializable

```
public class ProveSerialization {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    
        Save obj = new Save();
        obj.a = 4;

        File f = new File("File.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(obj);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Save obj1 = (Save) ois.readObject();

        System.out.println(obj1.a);
        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println(obj1);
        System.out.println(obj.equals(obj1));
        System.out.println(obj == obj1);
```

Output:

```
4
Save@14ae5a5
Save@6d03e736
false
false
```

Comment: Can you post a full program? What `mySaveObj.equals(anotherSaveObj)` does dependes quite a lot on how (or if) it is defined in `Save`

Answer (score 1):

Check the implementation of `equals` in the Object class; it compares the **identity** of two objects, which can only be true if the two objects occupy the very same space in memory. However, by serializing your object, you effectively create a new one (which is fine, as you might even intent to exchange your serialized object between two VMs. As a result, a serialized object can never be *the same* as it was before.

However, if you intend to loosen the definition of `equals` for your `Save` object, keep in mind that you could override the method. But I guess, that is OT, right?

Comment: I believe the issue with `equals` (that probably none is defined) is exactly the cause of the perceived behavior.